# Autohotkey Directives

Tags: keyboard, autohotkey

I get the following error when trying to create the following autohotkey.

> #If test
>   Error: This line does not contain a recognized action.

Why can't I use #If directives in autohotkey currently?

```
test=1
#If test
  a::b
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should update your AHK to [AutoHotkey_L](http://ahkscript.org/download/) (AutoHotkey 1.1.*).

> #If is only available in
>   AutoHotkey_L and AutoHotkey v2.

[source](http://brigand.github.io/ahkbook/en/Directives.html)